# How to filter an UltraGrid based on membership in a collection

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am currently working on a program using an where I need to filter an UltraGrid based on a few different conditions.

My problem is that I haven't yet found a way to express one of the conditions in the filter. I want one of the conditions to say "if the value in this row is a member of a certain collection, return true".

So for example, if my group is an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], a few example results would be:

```
value = 1: True
value = 2: True
value = 6: False
value = -1: False
```

Is anyone aware of a simple way of doing this that I'm overlooking? I'd prefer not to create a custom filter if that's doable. Nothing else on the [FilterComparisionOperator page](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.FilterComparisionOperator.html) appears to match what I'm looking for.

Comment: Filtering the datasource is not an option?

Comment: @Steve That might be an option but I'm not sure at the moment. The main issue is that doing so would break consistency with a few other methods already in place. This might be an option though.

Comment: However is not too much complicated to build a custom filter as [explained here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/WinGridFilterUIProvider_Adding_a_Custom_Filter_to_Enhanced_Filtering_UI_on_a_WinGrid.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I should have read more carefully for this. It looks like each UltraGridBand contains a ColumnFiltersCollection. So, to get the desired behavior, you can create separate ColumnFilters for each desired condition. In this case, one condition would be defined as:

```
Dim columnFilter As ColumnFilter
columnFilter.LogicalOperator = FilterLogicalOperator.Or

For Each element In MyCollection
    columnFilter.FilterConditions.Add(FilterComparisionOperator.Equals, element)
Next
```

and then you could do a:

```
Band.ColumnFilters.Add(columnFilter)
Band.ColumnFilters.Add(otherColumnFilter1)
Band.ColumnFilters.Add(otherColumnFilter2)
Band.ColumnFilters.Add(otherColumnFilter3)
```

See documentation (specifically Remarks) [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnFiltersCollection.html). Also this code's probably not 100% correct - haven't tested it yet. Should get the idea across though.

Comment: Yes it was simpler than I thought